# Apache POI XWPFTableRow drawing with double height

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi, xwpf

I am trying to draw a table in word document using Apache POI XWPF. But the table is drawing with double height rows like this[image]

Here is my source

```
             XWPFTable table = document.createTable(5, 1);
            for (Test t : tests) {
                    XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(k - 1);
                    XWPFTableCell cell = row.getCell(0);
                    XWPFParagraph ansParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(cell.getCTTc().insertNewP(0), cell);
                    XWPFRun ansRun = ansParagraph.createRun();
                    ansRun.setText(k + ") ");
                    cell.addParagraph(ansParagraph);
                    k++;
                }
```

how can I reduced the height of row.

Comment: What happens if you do it all as one run, without the second paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a table in Apache POI XWPF it already has a blank paragraph in every cell.
You are getting double height rows because you are also adding a paragraph in it.

So you replace the line

```
XWPFParagraph ansParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(cell.getCTTc().insertNewP(0), cell);
```

with

```
XWPFParagraph ansParagraph = cell.getParagraphs().get(0);
```

And remove the line

```
cell.addParagraph(ansParagraph);
```

Then it will work OK.